# Interface Design For iPhone X

Tags: iphone, user-interface, autolayout, storyboard, iphone-x

What's up guys,

Any clue what is that dark line at the bottom of the iPhone X screen and how to disable that? It is rather disturbing, I would say more than the top notch.

Especially in landscape mode: If I hug to the safe area at the bottom, then obviously that line is not covering my view, however, then either need to do the same at the top (losing valuable screen estate), or make the app look ugly by its asymmetric look.

Also about the notch in landscape mode: Obviously that can be very bad if that cuts off buttons etc, so maybe hug to the safe area is a better option, however what if one side you want to use up more screen? In the example screen below we could use the right hand side (except the corners of course), but if you rotate the device the other way around, then you would need to hug to the safe on the right and to the superview on the left instead.

Any good solution for these?

[image: iPhone X Portrait mode]

[image: iPhone X Landscape mode]

Comment: That line is the new home button

Comment: Oh I thought that is a swipe up gesture and no hoe button at all. So that means there is no way to remove that line?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's not a 'home' button we're used to, but a new home button, gesture based, yeah. And I really doubt it could be removed. I mean if you make a full screen game, then i guess that line will stay in the middle of your game, or it might disappear and you get it back by swiping from the bottom of screen up, like you get a menu...

Comment: Thanks. Not the best design decision from Apple but I guess we have to live with it. The notch is a killing too in landscape mode :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `auto-hide indicator` in requirements like playing Video in a Landscape mode.
But It will reappear automatically when user will touch a screen again.

To disappear indicator, you can `auto-hide` specifically for `viewController` as below

```
override func prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```